# How to transform a PDF Template into bytes with form field values filled

Tags: java, file, templates, pdf

In a web application developed using JSF pages and Java, I am working on a feature to populate a PDF template file that contains a form with fields, each having a specific "id."

I can already read this template in Java and fill in the desired data in these fields. However, when converting this file, with the successfully filled fields, into a byte array to send to an API that will save these bytes into a document again, the generated document has empty fields without the "Placeholder."

I can't say for certain if the data from these fields is being passed along with this byte array or not. It's also unclear whether the API understands these values and transforms the bytes into a file without this data.

It's crucial that the values from the form fields are passed and compiled into a new file with all the data.

Here is the template document being edited in LibreOffice Writer:
[PDF Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA5r4.png)

Below is my Java code where I read this exported PDF template to replace the fields and return the modified file in *bytes[]*:

```
public static byte[] gerarComprovanteFaturaCopel(String nome) throws Exception {
    PDDocument pdfDoc = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        InputStream modeloComprovanteEndereco = obterArquivoTemplateDocumentosDoDirResourcesComoInputStream(Dominios.NOME_TEMPLATE_COMPROVANTE_COPEL);
        pdfDoc = Loader.loadPDF(TreatFile.convertInputStreamToBytes(modeloComprovanteEndereco));
        substituirValorCampoPdf(pdfDoc, "campo_nome", nome);
        pdfDoc.save(outputStream);
        pdfDoc.close();
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Erro ao gerar Comprovante Fatura da Copel", e);
        throw new Exception(e);
    } finally {
        outputStream.close();
    }
}


private static void substituirValorCampoPdf(PDDocument pdfDoc, String nomeCampo, String valorCampo) throws Exception {
    try {
        PDAcroForm form = pdfDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
        if (Objects.nonNull(form)) {
            substituirTextoCampo(form, nomeCampo, valorCampo);
        } else {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        throw new Exception("Não foi possível encontrar um formulário válido dentro do arquivo template!");
    }
}

private static void substituirTextoCampo(PDAcroForm form, String nomeCampo, String valorCampo) throws IOException {
    for (PDField pdField : form.getFieldTree()) {
        if (nomeCampo.equals(pdField.getPartialName())) {
            pdField.setValue(valorCampo);
            break;
        }
    }
    form.refreshAppearances();
}
```

I also attempted to save the template with filled fields in a temporary directory, read it, and export it using Files.readAllBytes, but without success as well.

Comment: Please translate your question to English.